# RxJS - initial state and updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I need to obtain data from websocket and I want to use RxJS to do so.

There is a **websocket 1** for the latest initial data (~1000 records) and **websocket 2** for the incremental updates.

I have created two observables:

- `initalState$` that goes to **websocket 1** and fetches the initial data and then completes.
- `updateEvent$` that goes to **websocket 2** and continuously receives updates.

My initial implementation was:

```js
initialState.subscribe(initialData=> {
    console.log(initialData);
    updateEvent.subscribe(updateEvent => {
        console.log(updateEvent);
    });
});
```

The issue that I'm facing is that there is a gap after fetching the **initalState** and receiving the first update (**updateEvent**).

(I might lose update that happens after I fetch the initial data and before the subscribe).

Is there some practical way that I can create a new Observer that subscribes to both of my observers at the same time and buffer the **updateEvent** observer until the **initalState** completes and then have them in the right order "initial data first" then "updates" ?

Basically making the initialState just the "first" update, but making sure there aren't any missing updates after that.

Comment: Nesting subscribes in rxjs is almost always an indication of poor API usage and sometimes actual mistakes.

Comment: Check the buffer operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/buffer.html

Comment: If you don't want to loss any event, `merge` would work. But it seems that's not all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could achieve what you need by using `buffer` for the second websocket stream until the first one emits. Although, this chain gets a little more complicated because you want to start receiving values only after the first stream emits.

```
const initialStateShared = initialState.pipe(share());
const updateEventShared = updateEvent.pipe(share());

merge(
  initialStateShared,
  updateEventShared.pipe( // Buffer the second stream but only once
    buffer(initialStateShared),
    take(1),
  ),
  updateEventShared.pipe( // Updates from the second stream will be buffered first and then continue comming from here
    skipUntil(initialStateShared),
  )
).subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution is awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding it correctly what you want is to trigger both of the requests simultaneously and subscribe to them only if both are already available. I think you are looking for the `combineLatest` operator.

```
combineLatest([initialState$, updateEvent$]).subscribe(([initialState, updateEvent] => {
    console.log({initialState, updateEvent});
}));
```

This way the combined observable will wait for both initialState$ and updateEvent$ to have emitted something and after that it will trigger emits if either of the combined observables emits something. See https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html for more information.

Note: You should prevent doing a subscribe in another subscribe. It is often a code smell for doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was looking into combineLatest, but If I start the initialState$ and updateEvent$ together and then receive 10 update events before the first initialState completes, I'll loose all but the last update Event.

Comment: How would you buffer your updateEvent? Would you combine the updates or you will need all the updates that has happened until the initialState has loaded? And also are initialState$ and updateEvent$ observables of the same type?